# Make <0.5=Left; >0.5=Not Left

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhMcS.png)

In "Satisfaction_level" maximum is 1 and minimum is 0.
I need to make the "Satisfaction_level" become `<0.5 = "Left"; >0.5 = "Not Left"` in new column.

Please advise me.

Thanks!

Comment: You may get more helpful responses if you put a bit more effort into your question. For example, creating a minimal example of your data table directly within the question, rather than linked as an image, so that others can copy and paste it.

Comment: What should the response be when it is exactly 0.5 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Excel's `IF` function.  Enter the following formula into the column where you want this computed data:

```
=IF(A1 < 0.5, "Left", "Not Left")
```

Then copy this formula from the first row of the new column down to cover all of your data.